# Cache/Store Logon Information for OpenShift

Tags: openshift

I'm working a script that copies content from my local directory on a VM to an OpenShift pod.

The script works fine. My one complaint is that I need to use the interactive portion of `oc login` to authenticate my user each time I run my script like below:

```
oc login https://url.to.openshift

Authentication required for https://url.to.openshift:port (openshift)
Username: sampleUser
Password: samplePass
```

I know that I can run the command like so: 
`oc login --username=sampleUser --password=samplePass`
`oc login --token='sampleGeneratedTokenFromOpenShift'`

I'd rather not have a hard coded user/pass or token within the script.

Is there a way to store and default credentials for my user in a configuration file for use with `oc login`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the standard method is to create a service account, and use the token generated as a part of the `oc login` command.

Service Account Creation Command:
 `$ oc create sa <user>`

The service account then needs to be added to a project with a specific role.

Add Role to User Command:
    `$ oc policy add-role-to-user <role> system:serviceaccount:<project>:<user>`

The service account should be created and have a role on the project. In your login command add the token from the service account generated secret.

`oc login --token=generatedServiceAccountToken`